# How to "merge" sln files?

Tags: key-authentication, c++

Im pretty new to c++ and want to add keyauth to my simple application. I want to use this (https://github.com/KeyAuth/KeyAuth-CPP-Example) as a base. How do I add the solution file to my existing Project?

Answer (score 0):

The provided `example.sln` doesn't do much besides including the `example.vcxproj`. If you'd like to use that as a starter for you own code, you can add the *project* to your solution.

Comment: I don't really want to use it as a starter, I want to add the main cpp code from my application after the example main.cpp code. But my code has many dependencies so when I add it to  the example, it doesn't find the includes.

Comment: That'd essentially be equivalent to writing your `.sln` from scratch. I'd suggest the reverse and add `main.cpp`, `auth.hpp` and `skStr.h` to your existing solution.